# Forwarded emails from Gmail show original sender, want headers showing me instead

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, email-headers

I set up Gmail to auto-forward my email to a different address. However, when forwarded, the email appears to come from the original sender, instead of my email address.

Can I change this behaviour so forwarded emails are seen as sent by me in the header information?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for resending rather than autoforwarding. Gmail only offers autoforwarding. However, some downloadable email clients offer a resend feature. You can download your Gmail messages to any email client of your choice using [POP or IMAP](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=12769).