# Gmail forwarding issue

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forwarded emails from Gmail show original sender, want headers showing me instead](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/forwarded-emails-from-gmail-show-original-sender-want-headers-showing-me-instead)

An email was forwarded to me and has the information of the original sender, but the message is shown as being from the address that forwarded it to me. Can I change the address to show who the email was originally sent from without having to go into the email? I have gmail, the forwarding address was from outlook.

Answer (score 0):

No. The "from" address will have to remain the address of the person who actually sent it. The best you can do is make a label to categorize it.